# validate confirmation password in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

How to validate password confirmation in react form?

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.username) {
    errors.username = 'Required';
  }
  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = 'Required';
  }
  if (!values.confirmpassword ) {
    errors.confirmpassword = 'Required' ;
  }

   return errors;


};

export default validate;
```

Here is my validation page I tried confirm password validation during mismatches occurs... That doesn't works.. Is there anyone willing to help me??

Comment: can you share the code where you are using validate?

Comment: It's just a simple validation form.. https://codesandbox.io/s/nKlYo387 This is the code site.. actually i tried to implement it with confirm password but doesn't workout..

Comment: Please add tag `redux-form` to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following logic.

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.username) {
    errors.username = 'Required';
  }
  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = 'Required';
  }
  if (!values.confirmpassword ) {
    errors.confirmpassword = 'Required' ;
  } else if (values.confirmpassword !== values.password) {
    errors.confirmpassword = 'Password mismatched' ;
  }

   return errors;


};

export default validate;
```